# LINQ & C#: Sort a list based on conditions

Tags: linq, sorting, conditional-statements

In C#, I would like to sort a list of objects containing the int property 'XValue' based on the following rules.

- the sorted list contains all objects of the initial list
- picking objects from the initial list is conducted in cycles
- in each cycle, 4 or less objects are picked
- in each cycle, those (up to 4) objects are picked, containing the lowest XValues, but the difference of the XValues must be at least 10

Example:
the XValues are 0; 5; 10; 15; 20; 25; 30; 35; 40; 45; 50

cycle 1 picks 0; 10; 20; 30

cycle 2 picks 5; 15; 25; 35

cycle 3 picks 40; 50

cycle 4 picks 45

the sorted list would be 0; 10; 20; 30; 5; 15; 25; 35; 40; 50; 45

I guess, using LINQ would be the recommended precedure.

Many thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Have you tried to solve this problem yourself, and if not, why not?

Comment: "using LINQ would be the recommended procedure." I disagree - this sounds like a job for a custom loop and will require multiple iterations, which is not as easy to do in Linq.

Comment: It probably even isn't possible in Linq - "sorting" in linq requires an absolute definition of "order" between two arbitrary items - in your case "order" is determined by the presence of other items in the list, and will change depending on the contents of the list. e.g. in your example, `5` is "greater than" `20` because of the presence of `0`. If you remove `10` form the list, then `5` becomes "less than" 20.  That's not possible in Linq.

Comment: So - try it using `for` and `while` loops until the entire list is "sorted" - if you get stuck, come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while because of other projects, but I figured it out how to solve the sorting issue.

I am glad you did not just offer me a solution but 'forced' me to try it by myself.

So what I did was to first presort the objects based on their x values (in case they are not sorted). Furthermore, I added a property 'isSorted' (bool) the the objects, initialized with false. Then I looped over all objects which have isSorted == false and added the items to a new list based on the above mentioned conditions.

So, LINQ is only used for presorting. Afterwards, simple loops are the key.